# Is it possible to set up a Raydium LP from on chain using CPI?

Tags: cpi, liquiditypool

i would like my on-chain program to set up a LP for tokens using Raydium (though happy to use something else), but I can't find any reference/docs on whether this is possible.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and how to start?

Many Thanks

Comment: It looks like https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-contract-instructions/tree/master has the Rust bindings for the contracts, so you should be able to piece something together to do what you want on-chain from these libraries!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. [Raydium github](https://github.com/raydium-io) has many implementation examples for LPing or creating pools from your CLI.

The demo sdk has implementation examples of any basic function interacting with Raydium programs.
Raydium Demo-SDK: https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V1-demo/tree/master/src

Raydium TS SDK: https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk